# Editable widget not responsive in jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm following along almost exactly with the [editable widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html) example from jQuery tablesorter.  The table sort functionality works, but the editable functionality does not (in Chrome or Firefox):

> https://jsfiddle.net/uofekcrw/1/

Using:

- jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/css/theme.default.min.css
- jquery-3.3.1.min.js
- jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.js
- jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js

in that order.  Am I missing a script here?

---

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>tablesorter example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- load jQuery and tablesorter scripts -->
  <!-- widgets required for editable mode (I think) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/css/theme.blue.min.css" integrity="sha256-Xj5kQBWJMyOV0+sPr+wIBUHXdoZ00TPgT+RuiyOXtzo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" integrity="sha256-vtbCELc4mfidIiNdxWDVPvAK5AI86PbpSotyWoGUyxE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js" integrity="sha256-46l1q40VwOPnofvWNG4vQuFjxEnidAIBBn75kgKnI6c=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    .tablesorter tbody > tr > td > div[contenteditable=true]:focus {
      outline: #08f 1px solid;
      background: #eee;
      resize: none;
    }
    td.no-edit, span.no-edit {
      background-color: rgba(230,191,153,0.5);
    }
    .focused {
      color: blue;
    }
    td.editable_updated {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="table" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="db-row-344">
        <td class="no-edit">Peter</td>
        <td>Parker</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>$9.99</td>
        <td>20%</td>
        <td>Jul 6, 2006 8:14 AM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="db-row-884">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Hood</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>$19.99</td>
        <td>25%</td>
        <td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="db-row-234">
        <td>Clark</td>
        <td>Kent</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>$15.89</td>
        <td>44%</td>
        <td>Jan 12, 2003 11:14 AM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="db-row-756">
        <td>Bruce</td>
        <td>Almighty</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>$153.19</td>
        <td>44%</td>
        <td>Jan 18, 2001 9:12 AM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="db-row-232">
        <td>Bruce</td>
        <td>Evans</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$13.19</td>
        <td>11%</td>
        <td>Jan 18, 2007 9:12 AM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>

$(function() {

  $("#table")
    .tablesorter({
      theme : 'blue',

      widgets: ['editable'],
      widgetOptions: {
        editable_columns       : [0,1,2],       // or "0-2" (v2.14.2); point to the columns to make editable (zero-based index)
        editable_enterToAccept : true,          // press enter to accept content, or click outside if false
        editable_autoAccept    : true,          // accepts any changes made to the table cell automatically (v2.17.6)
        editable_autoResort    : false,         // auto resort after the content has changed.
        editable_validate      : null,          // return a valid string: function(text, original, columnIndex) { return text; }
        editable_focused       : function(txt, columnIndex, $element) {
          // $element is the div, not the td
          // to get the td, use $element.closest('td')
          $element.addClass('focused');
        },
        editable_blur          : function(txt, columnIndex, $element) {
          // $element is the div, not the td
          // to get the td, use $element.closest('td')
          $element.removeClass('focused');
        },
        editable_selectAll     : function(txt, columnIndex, $element) {
          // note $element is the div inside of the table cell, so use $element.closest('td') to get the cell
          // only select everthing within the element when the content starts with the letter "B"
          return /^b/i.test(txt) && columnIndex === 0;
        },
        editable_wrapContent   : '<div>',       // wrap all editable cell content... makes this widget work in IE, and with autocomplete
        editable_trimContent   : true,          // trim content ( removes outer tabs & carriage returns )
        editable_noEdit        : 'no-edit',     // class name of cell that is not editable
        editable_editComplete  : 'editComplete' // event fired after the table content has been edited
      }
    })
    // config event variable new in v2.17.6
    .children('tbody').on('editComplete', 'td', function(event, config) {
      var $this = $(this),
        newContent = $this.text(),
        cellIndex = this.cellIndex, // there shouldn't be any colspans in the tbody
        rowIndex = $this.closest('tr').attr('id'); // data-row-index stored in row id

      // Do whatever you want here to indicate
      // that the content was updated
      $this.addClass( 'editable_updated' ); // green background + white text
      setTimeout(function() {
        $this.removeClass( 'editable_updated' );
      }, 500);

      /*
      $.post("mysite.php", {
        "row"     : rowIndex,
        "cell"    : cellIndex,
        "content" : newContent
      });
      */
    });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix: the editable functionality needs `widget-editable.min.js`, not just `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js`.  For confirmation of that, have a look at the [example source](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html) underlying page HTML.

Adding:

```
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/widgets/widget-editable.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-s3IhRQ3CEMOyD3EBcKmhdZwkrQXtPA8Z8Lz8sEmjCX8="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
```

Fixed things here.

Updated JSFiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/n7hjow82/